# Write to shared txt file or DB table from web service?

Tags: ajax, web-services, json

I am developing a web service that will be invoked (using JSON) from client side each time the selection of a drop down changes. 
The goal is to register each "intermediate" change (on client side) using the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event and before submitting the form to the Server.

Each new selected value will be written to a shared txt file calling a relative web method via Ajax/JSON.

Would it be better to write these changes to a txt file (having to implement a lock/unlock policy to assure exclusive access) or rather define a DB table and save the changes there?

Everyday the web app will have around 10 to 20 active users that might potentially changes the DropDownLists and usually the right value will be selected at first, hence generally no more than one "intermediate" entry would be registered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the filesystem. It's slow. Use mongodb via a node.js webserver.

http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Homer6.
My application already uses MS SQL Server as DB and asp.NET for the code. I will use Jquery Ajax/JSON to track changes on client side (before submitting) and for each change call a web method (developed by C#) to write this information.
My worries were to introduce too many DB connections since each time a user change a dropDown a new INSERT would be executed.

Comment: Well, in that case use the existing database. Filesystem access should be limited as it doesn't scale across many webservers without a shared filesystem.

Comment: Actually the application would run only on one Server, therefore each access would be done to the same txt file contained in the Server where DB and code reside.
My doubts lie more on a performance point of view: whether would it be better to reduce the DB interactions or IO writes.

Comment: Well if the DB blocks and writes to disk, then it'll be as slow as a disk access anyways. I'd still go DB. The lookups will at least be from memory, even if they are over network.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds exactly like what you would want to use a database for, since [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) is already implemented there.

If you want a real headache (and a programming challenge!) trying to debug overlapping writes, resource starvation and deadlocks, by all means, go with a shared text file!